# Modify the column headers of a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, indexing

I have this column header:

[image]

I put these into a list by `x = list(df)` and the type of `x` is a string. I want to put these into another list of strings but converting them into 8/18, 7/18,6/18, etc...

Here is the df.head() output:

[image]

Output of `print(df.columns)`

```
<class 'str'>
Index(['NDD 8/31', 'Aug 2018(P&I Applied)', 'Jul 2018(P&I Applied)',
       'Jun 2018(P&I Applied)', 'May 2018(P&I Applied)',
       'Apr 2018(P&I Applied)', 'Mar 2018(P&I Applied)',
       'Feb 2018(P&I Expected)', 'Jan 2018(P&I Applied)',
       'Dec 2017(P&I Applied)', 'Nov 2017(P&I Applied)',
       'Oct 2017(P&I Applied)', 'Sep 2017(P&I Applied)',
       'Paystring as of cut off as if 10.31',
       'Paystrings as of
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add the output of print(df.columns) to the question?

Comment: @ScottBoston Added

Comment: Do you want to replace `Jun 2018 -> 6/18` only, or should the entire column name be `6/18`?

Comment: @MatthiasOssadnik No I do not need to modify the data frame, I just want to convert Jun 2018 - > 6/18 and put it into a vector or list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to `datetime` and then use [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html). The below logic also ensures non-date columns remain unchanged.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Aug 2018(P&I Applied)', 'Jul 2018(P&I Applied)',
                           'Jun 2018(P&I Applied)', 'Paystring as of cut off as if 10.31'])

dates = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(df.columns.str[:8], errors='coerce'))

df.columns = dates.dt.strftime('%m/%y').mask(dates.isnull(), pd.Series(df.columns))

print(df.columns)

# Index(['08/18', '07/18', '06/18', 'Paystring as of cut off as if 10.31'], dtype='object')

print(dates.dt.month)

# 0    8.0
# 1    7.0
# 2    6.0
# 3    NaN
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: Could you re-edit your answer to include the data frame I have?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx, No I can't, because your question doesn't have a complete dataframe.

Comment: Okay, how would I convert the series into a string?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx, I don't understand your question, maybe `str(my_series)` ?

Comment: Quick question how do I just get the months from dates list?

Comment: `dates.dt.month` ?

Comment: That does not work as I did this: as_of_date = as_of_date[1:13].to_string()